# Solving linter error- 'shallow' is not defined no-undef

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, babeljs, eslint, enzyme

I am using JEST and Enzyme. In my eslint file I have added jest as true under env. But I get a lint error for shallow as I have included it globally. **Error is- error  'shallow' is not defined  no-undef**

**setupTests.js**

```
//as we are accessing our application with a http://localhost prefix, we need to update our jest configuration

import { shallow, render, mount, configure } from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';
// React 16 Enzyme adapter
configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });
// Make Enzyme functions available in all test files without importing
global.shallow = shallow;
global.render = render;
global.mount = mount;
```

**.eslintrc**

```
{
  parser: "babel-eslint",
  "extends": ["airbnb"],
  "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "jest": true
  },
  "rules": {
    "max-len": [1, 200, 2, {ignoreComments: true}],
    "react/jsx-filename-extension": [1, { "extensions": [".js", ".jsx"] }],
    "no-underscore-dangle": [0, { "allow": [] }],
    "jsx-a11y/label-has-associated-control": [
      "error", {
        "required": {
          "every": [ "id" ]
        }
      }
    ],
    "jsx-a11y/label-has-for": [
      "error", {
        "required": {
          "every": [ "id" ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**app.test.js**

```
import React from 'react';

import { LoginFormComponent } from '../../components';

describe('LoginForm', () => {
  const loginform = shallow(<LoginFormComponent />);

  it('renders correctly', () => {
    expect(loginform).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});
```

**package.json**

```
 "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server --historyApiFallback true --port 8888 --content-base build/",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint ./src",
    "lintfix": "eslint ./src --fix"
  },
  "jest": {
    "verbose": true,
    "testURL": "http://localhost/",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.js$": "babel-jest"
    },
    "setupFiles": [
      "./setupTests.js"
    ],
    "snapshotSerializers": [
      "enzyme-to-json/serializer"
    ]
  },
```

The error comes in my app.test.js where I am trying to use shallow. Do I have to add something in my eslint config for **enzyme** the way I have made **jest** as true?

Comment: I think you missed to include this module before using shallow: 

     import { shallow, render, mount } from 'enzyme';

Comment: @ChetanSinghal I made shallow, render, mount this global in my setupTests.js, the test cases are running fine, I just get linter error

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about add global statement? [eslint no-undef docs](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-undef)

```
/*global someFunction b:true*/
/*eslint no-undef: "error"*/

var a = someFunction();
b = 10;
```

or set global on `.eslintrc` ([eslint global](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#specifying-globals))

```
{
    "globals": {
        "shallow": true,
        "render": true,
        "mount": true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Updated **.eslintrc**

```
{
  parser: "babel-eslint",
  "extends": ["airbnb"],
  "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "jest": true
  },
  "globals": {
    "shallow": true
  },
  "rules": {
    "max-len": [1, 200, 2, {ignoreComments: true}],
    "react/jsx-filename-extension": [1, { "extensions": [".js", ".jsx"] }],
    "no-underscore-dangle": [0, { "allow": [] }],
    "jsx-a11y/label-has-associated-control": [
      "error", {
        "required": {
          "every": [ "id" ]
        }
      }
    ],
    "jsx-a11y/label-has-for": [
      "error", {
        "required": {
          "every": [ "id" ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since globals are only used in test files the best practise is not to set them globally but only for the test files. That can be done by using `overrides` property with proper `files` glob:

```js
  overrides: [
    {
      files: "*.test.js",
      globals: {
        shallow: true,
        render: true,
        mount: true,
      },
    },
  ],
```

Full `.eslintrc` after addition in the snippet.

```js
{
  "parser": "babel-eslint",
  "extends": ["airbnb"],
  "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "jest": true
  },
  "rules": {
    "max-len": [1, 200, 2, { "ignoreComments": true }],
    "react/jsx-filename-extension": [1, { "extensions": [".js", ".jsx"] }],
    "no-underscore-dangle": [0, { "allow": [] }],
    "jsx-a11y/label-has-associated-control": [
      "error",
      {
        "required": {
          "every": ["id"]
        }
      }
    ],
    "jsx-a11y/label-has-for": [
      "error",
      {
        "required": {
          "every": ["id"]
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "overrides": [
    {
      "files": "*.test.js",
      "globals": {
        "shallow": true,
        "render": true,
        "mount": true
      }
    }
  ]
}
```